# Conditional "at-least" in Python, with pseudo-randomiztion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to do pseudo-randomization, meaning to randomize something by respecting certain rules.

Imagine the following DataFrame:

```
ColX 
 N
 N
 N
 N
 N
 N
 N
 N
 D
 D
 D
```

N stands for neutral and D for deviant. Before having a Deviant, I would like to at least have two Neutrals (but there can be more neutrals between deviants) and everything must be in a random order.

As result: ColX should look like

```
ColX
 N
 N
 D
 N
 N
 N
 D
 N
 N
 N
 D
```

I was wondering what kind of function I could use in python (function in pandas or other packages) or R (any function in a library that permits this?)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please stick to one language in your questions and remove one of the tags.

Comment: The `At least` you are looking for is `>`.

Comment: @Gregor Yes I want to rearrange the input to meet my criteria. It's not true randomisation it's called pseudo randomisation.

Comment: I'd recommend using a while loop shuffling your vector and a function to check if your criteria are met. Psuedo code: `done = check(x); while(!done) {x = shuffle(x); check(x)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "correct" way of doing it. Correct in the sense that every legal combination is equally likely. The downside is that it is a bit more expensive than @BradSolomon's:

```
>>> def deviant_sep(N_D, N_N):
...     Didx = np.random.choice(N_N-N_D, N_D, replace=False)
...     out = np.zeros((N_N + N_D,), bool)
...     out[Didx] = True
...     Didx = np.flatnonzero(out[:N_N-N_D])
...     out[Didx] = False
...     out[Didx + np.arange(2, 2*N_D+2, 2)] = True
...     return np.array(['N', 'D'])[out.view(np.int8)]
... 
>>> deviant_sep(3, 8)
array(['N', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'D'],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> deviant_sep(3, 8)
array(['N', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'D'],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> deviant_sep(3, 8)
array(['N', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'D', 'N'],
      dtype='<U1')
>>>
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> repeat('deviant_sep(1000, 8000)', globals=globals(), number=1000)
[0.2079479000531137, 0.20392047404311597, 0.20519483496900648]
```

Explanations: I suspect what makes this slow is numpy's `choice` without replacement function which I think generates a full permutation and then truncates it.

The method works as follows: we can map legal patterns with `nD` `D`s and `nN` `N`s to patterns with `nD` `D`s and `nN - 2 nD` `N`s by removing 2 `N`s before each `D` and conversely any pattern of the latter kind to a legal pattern by inserting 2 `N`s before each `D`. This map is 1-to-1. And the unconstrained patterns we know how to draw with equal probability. So we do just that and then map to legal  patterns by inserting 2 `N`s before each `D`.

Comment: What would be the upper range on the number of (consecutive) N's here?

Comment: @BradSolomon That should be `N_N - 2 N_D + 2`, I think. But for the `1000`, `8000` example it occurs with very low probability.

Comment: Thanks it works but I had to add np.array. I don't understand how I can apply this to a list. I am still novice.

Comment: @PierreJardinet You mean you want the output to be a list? You can simply convert using `.tolist()` for example `deviant_sep(3, 8).tolist()`. Or if you want a dataframe `pd.DataFrame(deviant_sep(3, 8), columns=('ColX',)).

Comment: No actually I have already a list of 240 chars with D's (=48) and N's (=192) and I have to mix them up in order to to have at least two N before one D. But you could also have 6 N before one D.

Comment: In that case you'd do `deviant_sep(48, 192).to_list()`. Re `6 N` you mean as another minimum requirement (instead of 2)?

Comment: No I mean you could have so many possibilities and you should take all possibilities into account. Example : You could have=> N D N N N D N N D or you could have => N D N N D N N N D etc, the possibilities are enormous with N = 192 and D = 48. and every time the list is generated you would have a new list with a new randomisation.

Comment: That's exactly what my code does. Try calling it a couple of times and compare the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163518/discussion-between-pierre-jardinet-and-paul-panzer).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can do this with NumPy, with a tiny speedup for looping provided by [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
from itertools import repeat
import numpy as np


def gen_chunk(high=5):
    """Example: gen_chunk(high=6) --> array(['n', 'n', 'n', 'd']"""
    return np.append(np.repeat('n', np.random.randint(low=2, high=high)), 'd')


def gen_series(chunks=3, high=5):
    return np.concatenate([gen_chunk(high=high) for _ in repeat(None, 3)])


df = pd.DataFrame(gen_series())
```

Walkthrough:

You can independently generate each "chunk" of 2 or more N's followed by 1 D.  That is what `get_chunk()` does above.  In this case, it generates a NumPy array of N's followed by 1 D, where the number of N's is a random integer between 2 and your `high` parameter.

Then in `gen_series()`, you can build individual chunks (3 of them is the default here) and concatenate them into a single 1d array.

**Update**

The above uses a constant `high` parameter in each chunk's generation.  Perhaps this doesn't meet the definition of psueorandom that you are looking for.  To use a different `high` with each chunk generation, you could do:

```
def gen_series(chunks, max_high):
    """Use a randomly selected `high` value for each chunk."""
    highs = np.random.randint(low=3, high=max_high, size=chunks)
    return np.concatenate([gen_chunk(high=high) for high in highs])
```

Either construction should be fairly quick:

```
%timeit gen_series(chunks=1000, high=10)
# 36.9 µs ± 1.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: This answers the question. However how can I make the array constantly of the size of 240?

Comment: `gen_series(chunks=1000, high=10)[:240]`?

Comment: Are you using the first or second version from above?  One has a `high` parameter, the other has a `maxhigh`.

Comment: nvm us max_high = 10

Comment: yeah just figured it out